# Non recursive quick sort in Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, recursion, quicksort, rcpp

I used a `recursive quick` sort algorithm with this code in `Rcpp`:

```
void Quick(NumericVector arr,int left,int right) { 
  int i=left;int j=right;
  double tmp;
  double pivot=arr[(left+right)/2];
  while(i<=j){
    while(arr[i]<pivot)
      i++;
    while(arr[j]>pivot)
      j--;
      if(i<=j){
        tmp=arr[i];
        arr[i]=arr[j];
        arr[j]=tmp;
        i++;
        j--;

      }
    }
  if(left<j)
    Quick(arr,left,j);
  if(i<right)
    Quick(arr,i,right);
}


    // [[Rcpp::export]]
    NumericVector sort_quick(NumericVector A) {
      NumericVector tmp=clone(A);
       Quick(tmp,0,tmp.size()-1); 
      return tmp;
    }
```

How can I get an `iterative` process to speed up the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a common iterative implementation of quicksort, you emulate the call stack with a local array.  When you finish partitioning a subarray, you check to see if there are elements on the left side of the partition index.  If so, you push a pair of indices onto your "stack" representing that subarray.  Then, you do the same for the subarray on the right of the partition index.  In the next iteration of the loop, you pop pair of subarray indices from the stack, perform a partition on that subarray, and then do what I described above.

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterative-quick-sort/

I'm not sure that the performance gain is from this is super significant, but it's probably something.

Another thing that you might consider doing, for very large input sizes, is extracting the elements from the vector and putting them in a buffer, then sorting the buffer. The access overhead, at least for a std::vector, seems to be about twice that of going to memory directly, so this becomes worth it once you pass a certain input size threshold. This was something I discovered by accident when implementing a parallel mergesort algorithm.

Comment: I tried this code and it's working. There is no difference in time running !